# HTML Canvas disappears when I leave the browser window

Tags: canvas, window

HTML Canvas element disappears when I leave the browser window. What could be causing this problem? Here are screenshots of the page and the code:

1. [before leaving the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBttv.png)
2. [after leaving the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCX7i.png)
3. [HTML &JS Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQkm2.png)
4. [CSS Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPp5M.png)

Comment: Please don't ever screenshot code for posting on Stack Overflow. You can paste the code right into your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: It seems to me that the canvas is getting cleared, rather than disappearing completely. You can right-click on the page and select `Inspect Element` to confirm if the element is actually being removed from the DOM.

Comment: I think problem has opera because in chrome it works good.
Inspect Element http://imgur.com/f1oAWSk